# How to translate date_format (months words) using i18n?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, internationalization

I use a function in WordPress to display either the publication date of a post, or a custom update date if there is one set (stored in DB).

```
$custom_date = date_create(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cstm_update_post')[0]);
$PostDate = 'Pubilé le ' . get_the_date('d F Y');
$PostUpdate = 'Mis à jour le ' . date_format($custom_date, 'd F Y');
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cstm_update_post', true)) {
    echo $PostUpdate;
} else {
    echo $PostDate;
}
```

The problem is that the month name is not translated into French when the user displays the French post (I use WPML). So, I'm trying to figure out how to "convert" this line using the i18n process.

```
date_format($custom_date, 'd F Y');
```

should become something like this, I guess:

```
date_i18n(get_option('date_format'), $custom_date);
```

The month name is displayed in French, but first, it returns the actual date, and I don't know where to add the date format ('d F Y'). So, if anyone has an idea, it would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: `date_i18n( 'd F Y', $custom_date );`

Comment: Thank you very much Vijay, the date is correctly formatted now, but for some reason, it still displays the current date instead of the one stored in DB. I will investigate further... btw, I added the variable $custom_date in my first post.

Comment: the 2nd param should be the date timestamp, not the date string.

Comment: don't forget about `strtotime( $custom_date );`  To convert a standard formatted date to a timestamp.

Comment: Ok, I found a working solution, thanks to both of you guys :) 
`date_i18n( 'd F Y', strtotime(date_format($custom_date, 'd F Y')));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks (a lot) to @Vijay and @ArtisticPhoenix, I managed to find the solution :

```
$custom_date = date_create(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cstm_update_post')[0]);
$PostDate = 'Pubilé le ' . get_the_date('d F Y');
$PostUpdate = 'Mis à jour le ' . date_i18n( 'd F Y', strtotime(date_format($custom_date, 'd F Y')));
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cstm_update_post', true)) {
    echo $PostUpdate;
} else {
    echo $PostDate;
}
```